Is there a way to take a screenshot when before or after :context hook fails in rspec
I've implemented screenshot capturing for my automation project using rspec/capybara.
I was expecting capybara to take a screenshot each time a test fails, no matter where it fails (in preconditions or during test execution or in postconditions).
spec_helper has following code:
  config.after(:each) do |example|
    page.save_screenshot(example.description) if example.exception
  end

Majority of spec files have before :context block that executes once for all tests in scope of specific context.
The problem is that in case test fails in before or after :context block, screenshot is not taken. It is taken only in case test fails in 'it' block.
I've tried adding around :each hook in spec_helper file but it did not help unfortunately.
Here is the example of how it all works for a case screenshot is taken and for a case screenshot is not taken:
screenshot is not taken:
describe 'title', type: :feature do
  include_context 'User logged in'
  
  describe 'When user logged in' do

    before(:all) { do_something_causing_fail }

    it 'Verify something' do
      expect(something).to eq something
    end
  end
end

screenshot is taken:
describe 'title', type: :feature do
  include_context 'User logged in'
  
  describe 'When user logged in' do

    before(:all) {  }

    it 'Verify something' do
      do_something_causing_fail
      expect(something).to eq something
    end
  end
end


What's happening in the test setup where it fails? I'm not sure the after block is guarenteed to run in the case of a exeption for example. You might want to use something like around(:each) { |spec| spec.run rescue SomeKindOfError => e ... } if you want to ensure that the screenshot is taken.

Use Capybara and call save_and_open_page.
